# neo4jclient C# and CALL {} IN TRANSACTIONS syntax

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

Using the C# neo4jclient how can I formulate the following cypher query (possible since neo4j 4.4)

```
MATCH (n:Foo) where n.foo='bar'
CALL { WITH n
DETACH DELETE n
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS;
```

Best regards

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two options:

1. **Use apoc procedure** `apoc.periodic.iterate`

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (n:Foo) WHERE n.foo='bar' RETURN n",
  "DETACH DELETE n",
  {batchSize: 10000}
);
```

More about https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/

2. **Without apoc**
   Run the following query in the while cycle as long as the return value is higher then zero.

```
MATCH (n:Foo)
WHERE n.foo='bar'
WITH n LIMIT 10000
DETACH DELETE n
RETURN count(*) AS numOfDeletedNodes
```

In both cases, you should have index on `Foo.foo` property or the query may take really a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get yourself version `4.1.20` of the client then you can use it like this:

```
client.Cypher
  .Match("(n:Foo)").Where("n.foo='bar'")
  .Call("{ WITH n DETACH DELETE n}")
  .InTransactions(10000);
```

It wasn't in `4.1.19` so you'll need the very latest version.

Comment: thank you, getting closer:

Getting error :

Can only start inner transactions in an implicit transaction.


Here my simplified cypher. It shall only delete all documents in chunks, otherwise I might encounter java out of Heap errors.

 var query = client.Cypher
                  .Match("(n:" + typeof(T).Name + ")")
                  .Call("{ WITH n DETACH DELETE n}")
                  .InTransactions(10000);